# Sorting points in a clockwise direction

Tags: javascript, math, point

If I have a list of points `[(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)...]` is there any way I can arrange them so that they are in a clockwise direction?

By clockwise direction I mean clockwise relative to the center of the shape.

Comment: Yes, there are often many ways to do something in programming - the first step is often to try to write some code. Please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: You may need to say a little more about the points. For example a list of points could form a 1d line and not a 2d shape. It is not clear what clockwise would mean in that case.  Probably what you are looking for goes like this: 1) find the average x,y. 2) for each point use x-x center, y- y center and plug the values into atan2 to get an angle. 3) Sort the points by the angle.

Comment: Doesn't  this have a limitation? If I have the point (1,1) it will give the same angle as (-1,-1) because the slopes negative signs cancel out when the slope is gotten.

Comment: Are your shapes always convex? If not, then how will you know which points are considered to be neighbors?

Comment: @trincot, I don't think convexity is a problem here, from the moment you can calculate the centroid of the group of points, you can draw lines from this centroid to every point and get the angle they form with the x axis. From which you can then sort your points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have to find the center of the shape defined by your points, since the rotation will be defined with respect to this point.

Then you have to calculate the angle the points have with respect to the center and the `x` axis.
To calculate the angle, you can use `Math.atan2(y - center.y, x - center.x)`.

Then you order the points by angle using `Array.sort`.

Once the points are correctly ordered you should be able to draw a line that connects the points and does not intersect itself. I made a demo using a canvas. The starting point is shown with a square. I have drawn the `x/y` axis translated to the centroid of your points. I also added lines connecting the points to the centroid to materialize their angles.

```js
const width = 250;
const height = 250;

// Random points
const points = Array.from({ length: 20 }, () =>
  ({ x: Math.random() * width, y: Math.random() * height })
);

// Get the center (mean value) using reduce
const center = points.reduce((acc, { x, y }) => {
  acc.x += x / points.length;
  acc.y += y / points.length;
  return acc;
}, { x: 0, y: 0 });

// Add an angle property to each point using tan(angle) = y/x
const angles = points.map(({ x, y }) => {
  return { x, y, angle: Math.atan2(y - center.y, x - center.x) * 180 / Math.PI };
});

// Sort your points by angle
const pointsSorted = angles.sort((a, b) => a.angle - b.angle);

// Draw them
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let lastPoint = pointsSorted[0];

ctx.fillRect(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, 5, 5);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, center.y);
ctx.lineTo(width, center.y);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(center.x, 0);
ctx.lineTo(center.x, height);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.stroke();  

pointsSorted.forEach(({ x, y }) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.stroke();  
  
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 2, 2);
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(center.x, center.y);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'grey';
  ctx.stroke();  
  
  lastPoint = { x, y };
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Hope that helps!